# OPENJSON unable to parse Portuguese characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms, open-json

I'm trying to convert my JSON data into a table format in SQL Server Express 2019. Following are my JSON data:

```
    DECLARE @token INT;
    DECLARE @ret INT;

    DECLARE @url NVARCHAR(MAX);
    
    DECLARE @json AS TABLE(Json_Table NVARCHAR(MAX))
    
    SET @url = 'http://www.test.com/webservice.php?user=DHRWWF&pass=CVernise&key=DFGJRTSrnwieuwn3&format=json'
    
    EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @token OUT;
    IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to open HTTP connection.', 10, 1);
    
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @url, 'false';
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send'
    
    INSERT into @json (Json_Table) EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText'
    
    SELECT * FROM @json
    
    SELECT
        metadata.[col1],
        metadata.[col2],
        metadata.[col3],
        x1.[col1],
        x1.[col2],
        metadata.[col4],
        metadata.[col5],
        x2.[col1],
        x2.[col2],
        x3.[col1],
        x3.[col2],
    
    FROM OPENJSON((SELECT * FROM @json))  -- USE OPENJSON to begin the parse.
    
    -- At the highest level we n parts
    WITH (
        [Produts] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
    ) AS  Data
    
    -- Parse the Metadata
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([Data].[Produts])
    WITH(
        [col1] NVARCHAR(MAX),
        [col2] NVARCHAR(MAX),
        [col3] NVARCHAR(MAX),
        [col4] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON,
        [col5] NVARCHAR(MAX),
        [col6] NVARCHAR(MAX),
        [col7] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON,
        [col8] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON,
    ) AS metadata
    
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([Metadata].[col4])
    WITH(
        [col1] NVARCHAR(MAX),
        [col2] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ) AS x1
    
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([Metadata].[col7])
    WITH(
        [col1] NVARCHAR(MAX),
        [col2] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ) AS x2
    
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([Metadata].[col8])
    WITH(
        [col1] NVARCHAR(MAX),
        [col2] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ) AS x3
```

The result is:

| metadata.[col1] | metadata.[col2] | metadata.[col3] | x1.[col1] | x1.[col2] | metadata.[col4] | metadata.[col5] | x2.[col1] | x2.[col2] | x3.[col1] | x3.[col2] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AABBCC | BBCCDD | DDEEFF | 1 | 2 | `Sistema autom&aacute;tico` | ASDVDs | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

And a need this result

| metadata.[col1] | metadata.[col2] | metadata.[col3] | x1.[col1] | x1.[col2] | metadata.[col4] | metadata.[col5] | x2.[col1] | x2.[col2] | x3.[col1] | x3.[col2] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AABBCC | BBCCDD | DDEEFF | 1 | 2 | **Sistema automático** | ASDVDs | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

TY

Comment: SQL Server doesn't accept UTF-8, would it be possible to request UTF-16 from the webservice? Something like `http://www.test.com/webservice.php?user=DHRWWF&pass=CVernise&key=DFGJRTSrnwieuwn3&format=json&encoding=utf-16`

Comment: Good morning and thanks for the help. Did not work. I think we will have to use the N' I just don't know where.

Comment: The OLE automation procedure are obsolete and should not be used - simple searching will find many suggestions and discussions about their usage and alternatives.

Comment: Can you give me a suggestion so I can look it up?